# Jasypt: read configuration from external file

Tags: grails, encryption, config, jasypt, grails-2.2

I am using [grails Jasypt Encryption plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jasypt-encryption) to encrypt my data in the DB.

If I set jasypt configurations in my Config.groovy file like:

```
jasypt {
    algorithm = "PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC"
    providerName = "BC"
    password = "myPassphrase"
    keyObtentionIterations = 1000
}
```

then everything is working fine.

But if I move the jasypt configurations in an external file as mentioned in the [jasypt doc(External Config Files in Grails)](https://bitbucket.org/tednaleid/grails-jasypt/wiki/Home) then these configuration are not being accessed.

**How to access jsypt external configuration file?**

**Note:-** Using ubuntu

Comment: Could you show the part from your Config.groovy where you configure your external jasypt-configuration?

Comment: I am following this link (https://bitbucket.org/tednaleid/grails-jasypt/wiki/Home see the section:- External Config Files in Grails). I have never read external config file so I am not sure that I am doing it right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your Jasypt config block uses ConfigSlurper syntax, your external config file needs a `.groovy` extension (e.g. `.jasypt.groovy`)  Or, you could switch to Java `.properties` syntax.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, `.jasypt.groovy` works fine. Following is my working configurations `"file:${System.getenv('ENCRYPTION_CONFIG_LOCATION')}" ?: "file:${userHome}/.jasypt.groovy"`, working fine for System variable as well. THANKS..,.

Answer (score 0):

If you just copy-pasted this section:

```
def configFIlePath = System.getenv('ENCRYPTION_CONFIG_LOCATION') ?: "file:${userHome}/.jasypt"
grails.config.locations = [configFilePath]
```

pay special attention to the typo: in the first line it must be `configFilePath` with a lower-case `i`!!

Comment: Still it is not reading the config file. It is not showing me the saved values in the DB. If you want I can give you my sample project.